# Nginx Ingress Controller with Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I am a bit confused with the architecture of load-balancing K8s traffic with Nginx ingress controller.
I learned that an ingress controller is supposed to configure the load-balancer you're using according to ingress configurations.
So if I want to use Nginx ingress controller and I have a Physical server that is running Nginx that stands in front of my network, how can I make the ingress controller configure it?

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What are your exact configurations? Where is your cluster located?

Comment: Hi, this is more of a general question - is the nginx ingress controller supposed to (or can) configure an Nginx machine?

Answer (score 0):

Ingress exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource. You must have an Ingress controller to satisfy an Ingress. Only creating an Ingress resource has no effect. Take a look at the example graph below:

[image: Look at the example graph below:]

Nginx Ingress Controller is using service of type LoadBalancer to get the traffic enter the controller and then to get rerouted to particular services.

I strongly suggest going through the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) in order to get a good understanding of the topic and see some examples of using it.

> is the nginx ingress controller supposed to (or can) configure an
> Nginx machine?

[NGINX Ingress Controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress#nginx-ingress-controller-1) works with both NGINX and NGINX Plus and supports the standard Ingress features - content-based routing and TLS/SSL termination.